# if expression language does not found the object, what should be returned?

Tags: el

I got problem when I code,in my jsp page:

```
<body>
   <script>
      var a = "${testtesttest }"; 
   </script>    
</body>
```

the “testtesttest” object must be not found without doubt,but what should be returned?
In official doc, it says:

```
For example, when evaluating the expression ${product}, the container will look for       product in the page, request, session, and application scopes and will return its value. If product is not found, null is returned.
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html

I thought null will be returned,however, i will not ask question if as I wish..
Through firebug,the codes after compiled in browser below:.

```
<body>
   <script>
      var a = ""; 
   </script>
</body>
```

why not null?? What on earth the result is, i am confused..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${null}` is indeed printed as an empty string.

See also the second point of chapter 1.18.2 of [EL specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/expression_language-2.2-mrel-eval-oth-JSpec/) (`A` represents "any object"):

> ## 1.18.2 Coerce A to String
>
> - If `A` is `String`: return `A`
> - Otherwise, if `A` is `null`: return `""`
> - Otherwise, if `A` is `Enum`, return `A.name()`
> - Otherwise, if `A.toString()` throws an exception, error
> - Otherwise, return `A.toString()`

It's hard to give an answer to what exactly you want. If it would actually print null, then the generated JS code would end up like `var a = "null";` which is quite different from `var a = null;`. You should then conditionally print the JS variable with or without quotes. Also, it's unclear what exactly you ultimately want to do with this. Perhaps it's helpful to know that `if (a)` would still evaluate `false` when it's an empty string due to JS boolean magic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I know ${testtesttest } == ${null} and ${null} return "",your EL specification doc was a gift for me, thanks!     @BalusC

Answer (score -1):

The reason of get:

```
<body>
    <script>
        var a = ""; 
    </script>
</body>
```

is that when you do:

```
var a = "${testtesttest }";
```

what really is doing:

```
var a = "null";
```

what is traduced to:

```
var a = "";
```

Comment: The "what really is doing" part is completely wrong, or at least confusing and misleading.

Comment: you vote me with a negative and then explain the same like me? wow! thats great..

Comment: My answer is not the same.